# Can't input text after deleting it

Tags: javascript, dom, preventdefault

I made an input text that once it reaches 10 characters it will turn red. 
I cannot add text if i delete some of the input text that is already there.
It's a must that i have to do it with preventDefault.

1) How can i make my code work and let me input after i deleted some of the text.
2) Is there a way to do it without using addEventListener but still using preventDefault?
I'm rather new to this javaScript stuff. Thank you in advance.

```
function ceScriu() {

  var numeInput = document.querySelector("[name='nume']");
  var nume = numeInput.value;
  var nu = nume.toString().toLowerCase();
  var divInput = document.querySelector("[name='divul']");
  var div = nu.length;

  document.querySelector("[name='divul']").innerHTML = div;

  if (div > 9) {
    numeInput.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault()
    });
    divInput.classList.add("counter");
  } else {
    divInput.classList.remove("counter");
  }
}
```

the code is working fine. The counter turns red when it reaches 10. But if i write characters, delete them and then try again to write some more, i cannot input any characters.

Comment: As a note, i'm using preventDefault to stop all input at 10 characters, but i still want to be able to input characters if they are under the limit of 10.

Comment: I think it can be done by onChange function call from the input element.

Comment: well you disable keypress.... seems odd that you would do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Please check this pluker https://plnkr.co/edit/ny35WPX3fsTmw1oWY1j8

I modified your code to check for length inside the event listener as follows

```
window.onload = function () { 
  var numeInput = document.querySelector("[name=nume]");
  numeInput.addEventListener("keypress",function(event){
              var nume = numeInput.value;
              var nu = nume.toString().toLowerCase();    
               var divInput = document.querySelector("[name=divul]");
               var div = nu.length;
               document.querySelector("[name=divul]").innerHTML = div;
               if(div > 9){
                 event.preventDefault();
                 divInput.classList.add("counter");        
               }else{    
                 divInput.classList.remove("counter");
               }
  });

}
```

Comment: i've checked both and it doesn't seem to do the trick. The first one goes beyond the 10 characters limit and the second one still won't let me input text after i deleted some of the characters.

Comment: @ZiatcoFelix I have edited my response and provided working plunker.